# /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend been held by a ghost process

Tags: apt, dpkg

**I Have tried all the solutions mentioned in other posts but none work**. I am using ubuntu 20.04. Whenever I upgrade or even run `dpkg --configure -a` it gets stuck in a forever loop saying lock-frontend is being held by a certain process. However, when I try to kill the process or use `killall apt apt-get` it shows no such process and nothing is using apt respectively. No other application is running and have also rebooted multiple times.
Please help me here
TIA